# Issue with TextFieldParser in C#

Tags: c#, csv, generics, using, textfieldparser

[image: Screenshot of error placement]I am using Visual Studio 2013, .NET 4.5.2, OpenXml 2.5 on Windows 7 Enterprise. I created a snippet of code to import two .csv files into a pair of generic lists and to compare them for exceptions. When I went to build a generic class to load the .csv files, TextFieldParser would not work. It works within Main(), but not within a class.

Although I suspect the answer has something to do with "using alias within a namespace", it works perfectly within Main(). Microsoft has a disclaimer that the rhs cannot be a generic type, but if it works in one place, why not the other?

Is this expected behavior or is there a known workaround?

BACKGROUND: TextFieldParser is a VB.NET class that neatly handles parsing of .csv or fixed field files. Generic lists, or List, are list classes that can handle anything placed in them. In my case, I am using a record class as the object contained. OpenXml is a Microsoft technology for working with Office products to deal with XML config files or connection strings. I will be importing config settings to make the classes used generic. It is in trying to build a generic class for the TextFieldParser where I am having issues. Google has gotten me this far, but no farther.

The working code in Main():

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO;
using ExportToExcel;

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // HARD_CODED FOR EXAMPLE ONLY - TO BE RETRIEVED FROM APP.CONFIG IN REAL PROGRAM
        string hospPath = @"C:\\events\\inbound\\OBLEN_COB_Active_Inv_Advi_Daily_.csv";
        string vendPath = @"C:\\events\\outbound\\Advi_OBlen_Active_Inv_Ack_Daily_.csv";

        List<DenialRecord> hospList = new List<DenialRecord>();
        List<DenialRecord> vendList = new List<DenialRecord>();

        using (TextFieldParser hospParser = new Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser(hospPath))
        {
            hospParser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
            hospParser.SetDelimiters(",");
            hospParser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = false;
            hospParser.TrimWhiteSpace = true;

            while (!hospParser.EndOfData)
            {

                try
                {
                    string[] row = hospParser.ReadFields();
                    if (row.Length <= 7)
                    {
                        DenialRecord dr = new DenialRecord(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6]);
                        hospList.Add(dr);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error is:  {0}", e.ToString());
                }
            }
            hospParser.Close();
            hospParser.Dispose();
        }
```

The non working code in a class by itself:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO;
using ExportToExcel;

namespace InputSide
{
internal class CsvLoader
{
    private int columnCount = 7;    // backing store
    private string filePath;
    private List<DenialRecord> inputList = new List<DenialRecord>();

    public List<DenialRecord> InputList
    {
        set
        {
            this.inputList = InputList;
        }
        get
        {
            return inputList;
        }
    }

    // Default constructor
    internal CsvLoader()
    {
    }

    // Exposed constructor
    public CsvLoader(List<DenialRecord> InputList,  string FilePath, int ColumnCount)
    {
        this.inputList = InputList;
        this.filePath = FilePath;
    }

    // Load csv to List<T>
    public List<DenialRecord> CsvList(int columnCount)
    {
        private int columnCount;

        using (TextFieldParser csvParser = new Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser(filePath))
        {
            csvParser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
            csvParser.SetDelimiters(",");
            csvParser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = false;
            csvParser.TrimWhiteSpace = true;

            while (!csvParser.EndOfData)
            {

                try
                {
                    string[] row = csvParser.ReadFields();
                    if (row.Length <= 7)
                    {
                        DenialRecord dr = new DenialRecord(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6]);
                        inputList.Add(dr);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    // do something
                    Console.WriteLine("Error is:  {0}", e.ToString());
                }
            }
            csvParser.Close();
            csvParser.Dispose();
        }
        return inputList;
    }
}
}
```

EDIT:

Added error list:

> Error 1   } expected  c:\users\jas189\documents\visual studio
>   2013\Projects\InputSide\InputSide\CsvLoader.cs    43  10  InputSide
>   Error 2   Invalid token 'using' in class, struct, or interface member
>   declaration   c:\users\jas189\documents\visual studio
>   2013\Projects\InputSide\InputSide\CsvLoader.cs    46  13  InputSide
>   Error 3   ; expected  c:\users\jas189\documents\visual studio
>   2013\Projects\InputSide\InputSide\CsvLoader.cs    46  77  InputSide
>   Error 4   Invalid token '=' in class, struct, or interface member
>   declaration   c:\users\jas189\documents\visual studio
>   2013\Projects\InputSide\InputSide\CsvLoader.cs    48  41  InputSide
>   Error 5   Invalid token ';' in class, struct, or interface member
>   declaration   c:\users\jas189\documents\visual studio
>   2013\Projects\InputSide\InputSide\CsvLoader.cs    48  62  InputSide
>   Error 6   Invalid token '(' in class, struct, or interface member
>   declaration   c:\users\jas189\documents\visual studio
>   2013\Projects\InputSide\InputSide\CsvLoader.cs    49  40  InputSide
>   Error 7   Invalid token '=' in class, struct, or interface member
>   declaration   c:\users\jas189\documents\visual studio
>   2013\Projects\InputSide\InputSide\CsvLoader.cs    50  53  InputSide
>   Error 8   Invalid token '=' in class, struct, or interface member
>   declaration   c:\users\jas189\documents\visual studio
>   2013\Projects\InputSide\InputSide\CsvLoader.cs    51  42  InputSide
>   Error 9   Invalid token ')' in class, struct, or interface member
>   declaration   c:\users\jas189\documents\visual studio
>   2013\Projects\InputSide\InputSide\CsvLoader.cs    53  44  InputSide
>   Error 10  Invalid token 'if' in class, struct, or interface member
>   declaration   c:\users\jas189\documents\visual studio
>   2013\Projects\InputSide\InputSide\CsvLoader.cs    59  25  InputSide
>   Error 11  Invalid token '<=' in class, struct, or interface member
>   declaration   c:\users\jas189\documents\visual studio
>   2013\Projects\InputSide\InputSide\CsvLoader.cs    59  40  InputSide
>   Error 12  Invalid token '(' in class, struct, or interface member
>   declaration   c:\users\jas189\documents\visual studio
>   2013\Projects\InputSide\InputSide\CsvLoader.cs    62  42  InputSide
>   Error 13  Invalid token ')' in class, struct, or interface member
>   declaration   c:\users\jas189\documents\visual studio
>   2013\Projects\InputSide\InputSide\CsvLoader.cs    62  45  InputSide
>   Error 14  A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or
>   methods   c:\users\jas189\documents\visual studio
>   2013\Projects\InputSide\InputSide\CsvLoader.cs    65  21  InputSide
>   Error 15  Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file
>   expected  c:\users\jas189\documents\visual studio
>   2013\Projects\InputSide\InputSide\CsvLoader.cs    70  17  InputSide
>   Error 16  A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field,
>   method, or property
>   'InputSide.CsvLoader.filePath'    c:\users\jas189\documents\visual studio
>   2013\projects\inputside\inputside\csvloader.cs    46  68  InputSide
>   Error 17  A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field,
>   method, or property
>   'InputSide.CsvLoader.csvParser'   c:\users\jas189\documents\visual
>   studio 2013\projects\inputside\inputside\csvloader.cs 58  40  InputSide 
>   Error 18  A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field,
>   method, or property
>   'InputSide.CsvLoader.row' c:\users\jas189\documents\visual studio
>   2013\projects\inputside\inputside\csvloader.cs    61  64  InputSide
>   Error 19  A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field,
>   method, or property
>   'InputSide.CsvLoader.row' c:\users\jas189\documents\visual studio
>   2013\projects\inputside\inputside\csvloader.cs    61  72  InputSide
>   Error 20  A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field,
>   method, or property
>   'InputSide.CsvLoader.row' c:\users\jas189\documents\visual studio
>   2013\projects\inputside\inputside\csvloader.cs    61  80  InputSide
>   Error 21  A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field,
>   method, or property
>   'InputSide.CsvLoader.row' c:\users\jas189\documents\visual studio
>   2013\projects\inputside\inputside\csvloader.cs    61  88  InputSide
>   Error 22  A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field,
>   method, or property
>   'InputSide.CsvLoader.row' c:\users\jas189\documents\visual studio
>   2013\projects\inputside\inputside\csvloader.cs    61  96  InputSide
>   Error 23  A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field,
>   method, or property
>   'InputSide.CsvLoader.row' c:\users\jas189\documents\visual studio
>   2013\projects\inputside\inputside\csvloader.cs    61  104 InputSide
>   Error 24  A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field,
>   method, or property
>   'InputSide.CsvLoader.row' c:\users\jas189\documents\visual studio
>   2013\projects\inputside\inputside\csvloader.cs    61  112 InputSide
>   Error 25  'InputSide.CsvLoader.CsvList(int)': not all code paths return
>   a value   c:\users\jas189\documents\visual studio
>   2013\projects\inputside\inputside\csvloader.cs    42  35  InputSide
>   Error 26  'InputSide.CsvLoader.csvParser' is a 'field' but is used like
>   a 'type'  c:\users\jas189\documents\visual studio
>   2013\projects\inputside\inputside\csvloader.cs    48  17  InputSide
>   Error 27  'Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FieldType.Delimited' is a
>   'field' but is used like a 'type' c:\users\jas189\documents\visual
>   studio 2013\projects\inputside\inputside\csvloader.cs 48  53  InputSide 
>   Error 28  'InputSide.CsvLoader.csvParser' is a 'field' but is used like
>   a 'type'  c:\users\jas189\documents\visual studio
>   2013\projects\inputside\inputside\csvloader.cs    49  17  InputSide
>   Error 29  'InputSide.CsvLoader.csvParser' is a 'field' but is used like
>   a 'type'  c:\users\jas189\documents\visual studio
>   2013\projects\inputside\inputside\csvloader.cs    50  17  InputSide
>   Error 30  'InputSide.CsvLoader.csvParser' is a 'field' but is used like
>   a 'type'  c:\users\jas189\documents\visual studio
>   2013\projects\inputside\inputside\csvloader.cs    51  17  InputSide
>   Error 31  'InputSide.CsvLoader.csvParser' is a 'field' but is used like
>   a 'type'  c:\users\jas189\documents\visual studio
>   2013\projects\inputside\inputside\csvloader.cs    53  25  InputSide
>   Error 32  'InputSide.CsvLoader.row' is a 'field' but is used like a
>   'type'    c:\users\jas189\documents\visual studio
>   2013\projects\inputside\inputside\csvloader.cs    59  29  InputSide
>   Error 33  'InputSide.CsvLoader.inputList' is a 'field' but is used like
>   a 'type'  c:\users\jas189\documents\visual studio
>   2013\projects\inputside\inputside\csvloader.cs    62  29  InputSide
>   Error 34  'InputSide.CsvLoader.dr' is a 'field' but is used like a
>   'type'    c:\users\jas189\documents\visual studio
>   2013\projects\inputside\inputside\csvloader.cs    62  43  InputSide

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve] instead of explaining what your code looks like.

Comment: I can add the class used by the list, but it would be equally irrelevant. What the heck:

Comment: In what way does it not work?

Comment: It fails to recognize the "using" in using (TextFieldParser csvParser = new Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser(filePath)) as an alias and treats it as an include.

Comment: Please be very explicit in what way this fails. What does _"It fails to recognize"_ mean _exactly_? Do you get a compiler error? What exactly does it say? My best guess is that you actually created this class in a separate class library, and failed to add a reference to `Microsoft.VisualBasic` in this library...

Comment: Apart from what is probably a missing reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic: in `CsvList` 1) You can't declare `private int columnCount;` because that name is used as a parameter and 2) You should use `if (row.Length == 7)` because if there are less than seven elements then `DenialRecord dr = new DenialRecord(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6]);` will fail with an "Index out of bounds" error at run-time.

Comment: @Andrew The parameter and the property both use ColumnCount. All the references are there or it wouldn't work in Main(). The row.Length < 7 is a guard for fields containing commas that would up the count of fields. Less than cannot happen. I like the way you are thinking, though. Anything else you can think of? EDIT: I should add that ColumnCount was to be a passed parameter to make the row.Length able to handle other .csv files in the future. So far, it is unused.

Comment: @CodeCaster There are no errors. This is in writing the code. Both the class and Main() are the same project.The code in Main() was to see if I could get TextFieldParser to work with a generic list, which it does perfectly. The problem only shows up when placing it in a class. Maybe saying "the editor fails to recognize 'using' as a type alias in a namespace" would help.

Comment: It is unclear to me what you mean by "fails to recognize". Also, `using` as in `using (var foo = new Bar())` is not a type alias, `using TypeAlias = Namespace.Type` is, but you're not using that. Please just open the Error List (View -> Error List) and inspect the actual compiler errors you're getting.

Comment: @CodeCaster I can:

Comment: 'code'     Error 1 } expected c:\users\jas189\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\InputSide\InputSide\CsvLoader.cs 43 10 InputSide
    Error 2 Invalid token 'using' in class, struct, or interface member declaration c:\users\jas189\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\InputSide\InputSide\CsvLoader.cs 46 13 InputSide
    Error 3 ; expected c:\users\jas189\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\InputSide\InputSide\CsvLoader.cs 46 77 InputSide
    Error '/code'

Comment: @Andrew Morton: SOLVED! I gutted the "using" and started adding one line back in at a time. The declaration of 1) _private int columnCount_ was indeed it. It always helps to see things afresh on a Monday. I cannot upvote you as I do not have enough reputation, but I can say **thanks!**

Comment: @JimSnyder I converted my comment to an answer - if you accept it then you get a couple of reputation points. Glad you got it solved :)

Comment: @JimSnyder To accept an answer you need to click the hollow green tick next to it. If you weren't aware of that, it is possible that it would be prudent to go back through any previous questions you have had satisfactorily answered and accept them too ;)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Final working code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO;
using ExportToExcel;

namespace InputSide
{
    internal class CsvLoader
    {
        private int columnCount = 7;    // backing store
        private string filePath;
        private List<DenialRecord> inputList = new List<DenialRecord>();

        public List<DenialRecord> InputList
        {
            set
            {
                this.inputList = InputList;
            }
            get
            {
                return inputList;
            }
        }

        // Default constructor
        internal CsvLoader()
        {
        }

        // Exposed constructor
        public CsvLoader(List<DenialRecord> InputList,  string FilePath, int ColumnCount)
        {
            this.inputList = InputList;
            this.filePath = FilePath;
        }

        // Load csv to List<T>
        public List<DenialRecord> CsvList(int columnCount)
        {
            using (TextFieldParser csvParser = new TextFieldParser(filePath))
            {
                csvParser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
                csvParser.SetDelimiters(",");
                csvParser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = false;
                csvParser.TrimWhiteSpace = true;

                while (!csvParser.EndOfData)
                {

                    try
                    {
                        string[] row = csvParser.ReadFields();
                        if (row.Length <= 7)
                        {
                            DenialRecord dr = new DenialRecord(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6]);
                            inputList.Add(dr);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        // do something
                        Console.WriteLine("Error is:  {0}", e.ToString());
                    }
                }
                csvParser.Close();
                csvParser.Dispose();
            }
            return inputList;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from what is possibly a missing reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic:

In `CsvList`

- You can't declare `private int columnCount;` because that name is already used as a parameter and
- You *should* use `if (row.Length == 7)` because if there are less than seven elements then `DenialRecord dr = new DenialRecord(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6]);` will fail with an "Index out of bounds" error at run-time.